# Using CSS instead of <strong /> HTML tag

Tags: html, css, seo

I know that search engine bots pay attention to bold texts on the page, which are `strong` HTML tags. But do they still recognize if we use `font-weight:bold` instead of `strong` tag?

Is the HTML `strong` tag equivalent to `font-weight:bold;` for SEO?

Comment: It matters so little you literally spent too much time thinking about it already

Comment: oh, really? but i heard that strong tag is one of the html tags that matters for SEO.

Comment: It never had a lot of value and it is negligible now. The biggest problem with SEO nowadays is that old information is still prevalent even though it is obsolete and no longer true...if it ever was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I checked, most search engines do not factor CSS into rankings.

However, certain semantic tags such as `h1` and so on do factor in.

Of course, it all depends on what else is on the page.

**Aside**

I did a casual search on Google and found some discussion about hidden text, which is a tangent to your question but may be of interest:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=UpK1VGJN4XY

Comment: thanks... but do a SE bot see an element as bold if it is formatted with CSS?

Comment: My first guess is no, but a `<b>` or `<strong>` tag may alter how a a SE engine interprets the page.

Answer (score -1):

You can't expect all search engines to be bullet-proof, so the answer is, not all of them.
What you can do is use CSS to ensure that search engines like Google and Yahoo understand which words are important, without having to annoy your readers:

```
<p>This sentence contains several 
<strong>keywords</strong> of 
<em>significant importance</em>.
```

Append it with a new “SEO” CSS class:

```
<p>This sentence contains several 
<strong class="seo">keywords</strong> of 
<em class="seo">significant importance</em>.
```

And then write a simple CSS rule like this:

```
em.seo, strong.seo {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal; }
```

This CSS will prevent strong and em tags from being bold-faced or italicized on the screen while still allowing search engines to recognize the significance of those tags.

Source: http://www.cssnewbie.com/4-ways-css-can-improve-your-seo/

**Edit**: However, as suggested by the commenters below, be aware that SEs may recognize your low tricks. You should first consider a read to this [link](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12960/seo-how-to-separate-fact-from-fiction/13007#13007) before starting with hacks, and do it at your own risk.

Comment: This is black hat seo. Making strong tags look like normal text is exactly what search engines don't want you doing. This answer and link prove my comment above.

Comment: This question is not about good practices, it's about how currently search engines work. Since when is it wrong to make a website search-engine friendly without making it user-unfriendly?

Comment: A well built website is both user and search engine friendly. In fact, [the two are synonyms](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/13007/1253). If you have to resort to hacks or tricks **you're doing it wrong**.

Comment: Nice to keep in mind when SEOing :)

Comment: To claim that user-friendly and seo-friendly are isomorphic is just plain false.

Google can't do things that people can do.  Let's be honest...how many people have made all of their img alt attributes readable because they know for a fact that they will have disabled users visiting?  Google is the de facto largest beneficiary of these assistive technologies, and they need that help because _they aren't a person_.